# Верстка jQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, вёрстка

Возможно ли это?

Если да, то подскажите какими средствами,по возможности с ссылкой на ресурс.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если взять для примера ui-dialog, то изменить его верстку очень просто за html-структуру отвечает сам скрипт, который все генирирует сам, пример кода:

```
uiDialogButtonPane = $('<div></div>')
                .addClass(
                    'ui-dialog-buttonpane ' +
                    'ui-widget-content ' +
                    'ui-helper-clearfix'
                ),
            uiButtonSet = $( "<div></div>" )
                .addClass( "ui-dialog-buttonset" )
                .appendTo( uiDialogButtonPane );
```

думаю разобраться будет не сложно, можно спокойно добавлять свои теги или свои классы. А стили правяться через цсс, если есть желание можно отключить стандартные стили и самому все прописать под ваши нужды.

Comment: Уже сделал,спасибо за объяснение)